# How to access email messages from a linux web site backup

Tags: linux, email, email-client, webmail, roundcube

How can I access the mail stored in a full linux website backup?

If I unpack the backup on my Windows machine, I see the mail folders: /homedir/mail/[site_name]/[user_name].  But ... how can I access the messages?  I tried following steps for importing messages into Thunderbird, but since these folders do not contain *.eml format messages, Thunderbird doesn't find anything it is able to import.

Alternatively, I could upload the the .gz file of the site backup to a cloud server, unpack it, and do something there, in linux.  But I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple files with single message each in [user_name] directory then most likely you have your mail stored in [Maildir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) format. The [ImportExportTools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/) Thunderbird add-on claims to support this format.